# How to find Linux Distribution name using shell script?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, operating-system

I am writing a shell script in which I need the current operating system name to make it generic. Like:

```
if [ $Operating_System == "CentOS" ]
then
    echo "CentOS";
    # Do this
elif [ $Operating_System == "Ubuntu" ]
then
    echo "Ubuntu";
    # Do that
else
    echo "Unsupported Operating System";
fi
```

How will it be possible? Applying regular expression on `lsb_release -a` command or something else?

Thanks..

Comment: Yup - `lsb-release` is definitely the most robust, generic way to do it.  EXAMPLE: `lsb_release -d|awk '{print $2}'`.

Comment: or `lsb_release -ds`

Comment: lsb_release seems not available on CENTOS7 out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ lsb_release -i
Distributor ID: Fedora
$ lsb_release -i | cut -f 2-
Fedora
```

Comment: But, `lsb_release` not exists on centos 7.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the info from `lsb_release`:

```
echo "$(lsb_release -is)"
```

`i` stands for distributor id.

`s` stands for short.

For ex. It shows `Ubuntu` instead of `Distributor Id: Ubuntu`

There are other options:

> -r : release
>
> -d : description
>
> -c : codename
>
> -a : all

You can get this information by running `lsb_release --help` or `man lsb_release`

Answer (score 4):

EDIT 2:
As pointed out by [@Jean-Michaël Celerier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495627/jean-micha%c3%abl-celerier), some distros prefer to add double quotes.

This example...

```
awk -F'=' '/^ID=/ { gsub("\"","",$2); print tolower($2) }' /etc/*-release 2> /dev/null
```

... and this one ...

```
(awk -F'=' '/^ID=/ { print tolower($2) }' /etc/*-release | tr -d '"') 2> /dev/null
```

... can be used to remove them.

EDIT 1:
as suggested by [@S0AndS0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2632107/s0ands0), this is slightly better:

```
awk -F'=' '/^ID=/ {print tolower($2)}' /etc/*-release 2> /dev/null
```

try this one:

```
awk '/^ID=/' /etc/*-release | awk -F'=' '{ print tolower($2) }'
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, no need for the piping between `awk` though as `awk -F'=' '/^ID=/ {print tolower($2)}' /etc/*-release` does just fine, also for those with the want to detect distros based on Debian `awk -F'=' '/^ID_LIKE=/ {print tolower($2)}' /etc/*-release 2>/dev/null` is even closer to perfect for my use case.

Comment: Small improvement: remove the quotes that some distros like opensuse add: `awk -F'=' '/^ID=/ { gsub("\"","",$2); print tolower($2) } ' /etc/*-release 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

```
DISTRO=$( cat /etc/*-release | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | grep -Poi '(debian|ubuntu|red hat|centos|nameyourdistro)' | uniq )
if [ -z $DISTRO ]; then
    DISTRO='unknown'
fi
echo "Detected Linux distribution: $DISTRO"
```

Answer (score 1):

For almost all linux distros, `cat /etc/issue` will do the trick.

Edit: Obviously, no solution can apply to all distros, as distros are *free* to do as they please.

Further clarification: This is not guaranteed to work - nothing is - but in my experience, this is the method that most often works. Actually, it's the *only* method that works consistently (`lsb_release`, which was mentioned here, often produces `command not found`).

Comment: /etc/issue is not meant for storing information about the operating system and may contain whatever text the admin likes. I would never trust it for detecting operating system or distribution.

Comment: Specifically, /etc/issue is a text file displayed by getty at the console login. It is not guaranteed to contain any meaningful information at all about the distribution.

Comment: Normally I do `cat /etc/*ease`, since there is a `fedora-release` or `something-release` file in `/etc`.

Comment: this is not a reliable solution, since these are files for the administrator to put in whatever he wants.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what i get:**

```
#!/bin/bash

dist=$(tr -s ' \011' '\012' < /etc/issue | head -n 1)

check_arch=$(uname -m)

echo "[$green+$txtrst] Distribution Name: $dist"
```

Answer (score -3):

I'd use `uname -a`

```
robert@debian:/tmp$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
```