# How to detect OS system using BASH?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bash-completion

The script should be able to detect the operating system that is running.
The alternatives OS is Arch Linux, Centos and Ubuntu.

````
os=$(uname) 
if [ "$os" == "Arch" ]; then   
  echo "Arch Linux detected" 
elif [ "$os" == "CentOS" ]; then   
  echo "CentOS detected" 
elif [ "$os" == "Ubuntu" ]; then   
  echo "Ubuntu detected" 
else   
  echo "Unknown OS detected"
fi```

Output: Unknown OS detected


I tried doing this:

\`del1()

{
os=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep "PRETTY_NAME")
}
del1

echo "The operating system is: $os"\`

The output: PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

But I want to check between Centos, Arch Linux and Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?
````

Comment: So you don't want to check for the **OS**, but for the **distribution** of your OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Linux Distribution name using shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581754/how-to-find-linux-distribution-name-using-shell-script)

Comment: Also see [How can I get distribution name and version number in a simple shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6345/264812).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uname` command will always return `Linux` when running on Linux, so of course that's never going to work.

Using `/etc/os-release` is probably the best solution, but don't `grep` it for information; the file is a collection of shell variables that you can source with the `.` command, so you can write something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/os-release

case $ID in
  ubuntu) echo "This is Ubuntu!"
    ;;

  arch) echo "This is Arch Linux!"
    ;;

  centos) echo "This is CentOS!"
    ;;

  *) echo "This is an unknown distribution."
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: This is the cleanest! `man os-release` for details on the variables. The variable `$ID` is the best choise to use. The file `/etc/os-release` is adopted by all linux distributions that use systemd. a bit more details here: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/os-release

Comment: Thanks for help, that made much more sense :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grep command to filter the output of the `cat /etc/os-release` command for specific strings that indicate the operating system.
For example, you could use the following command to check for Ubuntu:

```
os=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -o "Ubuntu")
```

You could then use an if statement to check if the variable os equals to Ubuntu:

```
if [ "$os" == "Ubuntu" ]; then   
  echo "Ubuntu detected" 
else   
  echo "Not Ubuntu detected"
fi
```

You can do the same to check for Arch Linux:

```
os=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -o "Arch")
```

And for Centos:

```
os=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -o "CentOS")
```

You can also use `cat /etc/*-release` instead of `cat /etc/os-release` for more general detection of the OS.

You can also use `lsb_release -a` command to get more details about the distribution and version of the OS.

```
os=$(lsb_release -a | grep -o "Ubuntu")
```

You can then create a function that check for each os one by one and print the output accordingly.

```
check_os(){
os=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -o "Ubuntu")
if [ "$os" == "Ubuntu" ]; then   
  echo "Ubuntu detected" 
else
  os=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -o "Arch")
  if [ "$os" == "Arch" ]; then   
    echo "Arch Linux detected" 
  else
    os=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -o "CentOS")
    if [ "$os" == "CentOS" ]; then   
      echo "CentOS detected" 
    else   
      echo "Unknown OS detected"
    fi
  fi
fi
}
check_os
```

Please note that this approach might not be 100% accurate and it is better to use the appropriate package manager commands to check the OS version and distribution.

Comment: (a) you shouldn't be using `grep`, and (b) if you **do** decide to use `grep`, you don't need to use `cat`: `grep -o Ubuntu /etc/os-release`

Comment: Don't make use of nested if-statements. Just use `case`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check the name of the OS, you can try;

```
source /etc/os-release
echo "The operating system is: $NAME"
```